# Stop program from crashing when pressing Enter

Tags: c#

So, today I decided to start learning C# from scratch. I've managed to make a little math problems program. The thing is, whenever the user just presses enter without entering a value (or anything which isn't a number), the program crashes. I've read something about TryParse but I just can't get it. 
Here's my code (part of it):

```
    {
        Random numberGenerator = new Random();
        int num01 = numberGenerator.Next(1, 20);
        int num02 = numberGenerator.Next(1, 20);

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome, user.");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Fail2:
        Console.WriteLine("¿What's " + num01 + "x" + num02 + "?");
        int res1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (res1 == num01*num02)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your answer is correct");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            goto Fail;
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`. Using `goto` isn't a good approach, `while` loop will be better

Comment: Also worth reading: [How to use the try/catch block to catch exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) and [try-catch (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-the-try-catch-block-to-catch-exceptions)

Comment: The TryParse methods family require at least two parameters. The first one is the string that contains the wannabe number, the second is the variable where the parsing result should be stored (if successful). If everything goes well TryParse returns true, otherwise it returns false and the second parameter is set with the default value for its type. No Exception is triggered if is not possible to parse the first parameter. This syntax requires the presence of the out keyword to allow storing the result in the passed parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello & welcome to StackOverflow! I have a couple of suggestions:

1. Avoid using `goto`
2. Replace all your `Convert.X` with `X.TryParse` whenever it's the user who gives you the value, since you don't know what it could be

```cs
Random numberGenerator = new Random();
int num01 = numberGenerator.Next(1, 20);
int num02 = numberGenerator.Next(1, 20);

Console.WriteLine("Welcome, user.");
Console.ReadKey();

// Always use a loop instead of goto statements!
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("¿What's " + num01 + "x" + num02 + "?");

    // Old line: int res1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    // Problem: this assumes that Console.ReadLine() returns a valid number, e.g. "3"
    //          but as you said, the user can trick you and put something else

    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int res1))
        continue; // This will rerun the loop from the top, so the user will need to re-write a response


    if (res1 == num01*num02)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is correct");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    else
    {
        break; // stop the outer loop on top
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use int.TryParse like this...

```
int res1 = 0;
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out res1)) 
{
    //failed;

}
if (res1 == num01*num02)
...
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1